# Lead layout when creating a lead from an account (in Lightning Experience)

Tags: leads

I would like to customize the lead layout, the one that is displayed when we click on "New Lead" from an account page in Lightning Experience. How do we do that? I tried Lead page layout, compact layout, mini page layout, compact layout... I couldn't find it. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Salesforce classic, go to settings->Create->Global Actions-> Global Actions.

Then you will see, `New Lead` action as below, here you can update the layout.

[image]